# How do I work out the cost benefit of optimisation?

Tags: optimization

I want to figure out how much money I'd save if I optimise some part of my web app.  If I save 100 cpu milliseconds over 50K calls to the app, how much electricity is that not using in a day?  How about over a year?

I've tried to find some figures thru google, but my googling mojo is failing me at present.

Comment: Also, how much will that refactoring cost you? If you save 100 ms in a function that runs once a month, but which you spend two hours optimizing, is it worth it?

Comment: I entirely agree, and that's why I'd like the figures.  In that case, it's a no brainer.  But, I was thinking of something that gets hit about 50k times a day.  The line gets a little blurier there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't calculate something that specific. You can only conduct an experiment and see what happens.

But honestly I would rather spend time refactoring code for better maintainability and adding new features the customers will like and pay for, so that I won't have to think about electricity.

Comment: ok, but now think of a scenario where I could apply that optimisation to an entire data center.......  My app may only have a small cost saving, but if you apply that to another 500 applications, the electricity savings may become more relevant.

Comment: No,  it's work related.  My app co-exists with about 100 other apps on a server farm, and that's about to be integrated into a larger context (not sure how many, but hundreds is reasonable).

Answer (score 1):

When "optimizing" it is always important to focus on what you want to "optimize" - in this case, your electricity bill. I would not even bother looking at changing code in an attempt to affect your electricity bill. I would look at the computer's power supply, cooling fans, heat sink, etc. and optimize those things for energy efficiency (buy new, more efficient components). More than likely it will cost less than several hours of a software engineer "optimizing" code for energy efficiency.